# How to take a returned value and set it to "x"?

Tags: c++

I am working on something for school and I am caught on a problem. Please understand I am very new to c++ and programming in general (past experience was only a bit of HTML). Anyways here is my question.

For example I am a student in school and I want to go to lunch. I go to lunch then spend x about of money then bring that amount of money back to main function.

```
    int lunch(int moneyL)
    {
        std::cout << Here is lunch! 4 bucks please";
        moneyL - 4
        return moneyL;
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "You are given 5 dollars to eat lunch" << std::endl;
        int money = 5;
        std::cout << "Lets go to lunch";
        Lunch(money)
    }
```

Again my question is (if I am being confusing) how do I set the money in int main to the money that is taken away in lunch?

Thank you

Comment: `money = lunch(money);`

Comment: Or pass by `reference`, `void lunch(int &moneyL)` and don't return anything.

Comment: in other words, you need to call the lunch() function and get the return value. your problem may also be that you're calling Lunch(money) and you should be calling lunch(money).

Comment: Also note that the statement `moneyL - 4` does nothing. To actually change the value you have to write `moneyL = moneyL - 4` or shorthand `moneyL-= 4`

Comment: And missing semicolon and quotes.  Please use the compiler to find the really basic problems with your code and fix those *before* posting it here.

Comment: Sorry about the missing semicolon / quotes. I gotta be goin crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to solve this:

**Solution1 (By return value):**

```
int lunch(int moneyL)
{
    std::cout << "Here is lunch! 4 bucks please\n";
    moneyL = moneyL - 4;
    return moneyL;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "You are given 5 dollars to eat lunch" << std::endl;
    int money = 5;
    std::cout << "Lets go to lunch\n";
    money = lunch(money)
}
```

**Solution2 (By reference):**

```
void lunch(int& moneyL)
{
    std::cout << "Here is lunch! 4 bucks please\n";
    moneyL = moneyL - 4;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "You are given 5 dollars to eat lunch" << std::endl;
    int money = 5;
    std::cout << "Lets go to lunch\n";
    lunch(money);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make two changes:

1) `return moneyL - 4;` in function `lunch` rather than the last two lines in that function (which also fixes the syntax error on the penultimate line due to a missing `;`)

2) `money = Lunch(money)` in `main` so the `money` variable is updated. (Not necessary at present but will future proof your code).

Function arguments in C++ are passed *by value*. Google that for more details. Moving forward, have a look at references and pointers: there are alternative formulations that would work for you but I think the one I've given you is the best for starters.

Comment: Function arguments in C++ are passed by value??? Isn't that subjected to the programmer's choice?

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner so let's answer clearly. If I'm explaining to a young physicist how an object falls in a vacuum on Earth, I will neglect to mention Coriolis displacement and Ricci tensors. And besides, every compiler I've come across optimises a reference out to a pointer.

Comment: @barakManos actually c++ arguments are default passed by value.  You can work around this by passing a pointer to the called function which will allow you to use the object pointed to, simulating a pass by reference option, but even in this case the pointer is actually still passed by value.

Comment: @barakmanos You can specify any value is passed by reference, but that is something you have to actively specify per argument.

Comment: That being said, I have a feeling that "passed by value" is analogue to "Coriolis displacement and Ricci tensors" in this case.

Comment: @theDarse: The terms "by value", "by reference", etc, are all **logical** terms. Those functions aren't very "real" too, you know? If you look at the disassembly, they are just memory addresses in the code-section of the executable image. You can just as well claim that everything is eventually converted into physical signals on electronic transistors. Though, you still want to distinguish between the different ways of passing arguments to a function. It helps to understand the language and "silently ignore" the underlying layer whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value by reference, this way:

```
#include <iostream>
void Lunch(int& moneyL)
{
    std::cout << "Here is lunch! 4 bucks please" << std::endl;
    moneyL -= 4; // another thing, this doesnt change anything unless it
                        // is coded as an assignation
    // you dont need to return the value
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "You are given 5 dollars to eat lunch" << std::endl;
    int money = 5;
    std::cout << "Lets go to lunch" << std::endl;
    Lunch(money);
    std::cout << "Money now: " << money << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I prefer moneyL -= 4;

Comment: Indeed. Especially if the student is hungry and makes multi-threaded calls to the function. (`-=` is atomic on atomic types; assigment is not).

Comment: Why the need to return the moneyL when you capture it by reference?

Comment: Fixed the answer.
As long as the compiler apply optimizations, there is no difference between moneyL -= 4 and moneyL = moneyL - 4 other than code aesthetic

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the complete question asked by you. My suggestion is, you should declare money and lunch as data member of the Student Class. Something like this.

```
class Student{
  public:
  int money;
  void lunch(){
    //implementation of lunch goes here...
    // subtract money here
  }
};
int main(){
  Student s;
  s.money = 10;
  s.lunch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is the most extensible. You can use this to solve "what happens if a student buys lunch for another student"? Encapsulation needs working on though.

Comment: This solution doesn't return the left over money to the main function (the main subject of the question).

Comment: Why do you want to return the money? .you can access the balance money in the main function as s.money

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is, as πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, to call

```
money = Lunch(money);
```

instead of

```
 Lunch(money);
```

Another solution is, to make the function take a "reference" instead of a "value" as parameter:

```
void lunch(int& moneyL)
{
    std::cout << Here is lunch! 4 bucks please";
    moneyL -= 4;
}
```

In your case, the variable of moneyL is a copy of moneyL in the main() function.
In my case, by passing int&, moneyL in lunch() is the same variable as in main(). So there is no need to return a value.

Tip: Read the chapter "Arguments passed by value and by reference":
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Edit:
Corrected "moneyL -= 4;" as πάντα ῥεῖ wrote it in the comment.